# MongoDB background indexing

Tags: mongodb, indexing, full-text-search

If I execute a text index in the background on MongoDB. Will this continue to execute even when I log out of the server?

```
db.test.ensureIndex({"name" : "text", "lastName" : "text"}, { background: true })
```

Comment: Yes, background index build does not depend on your mongo shell remaining active.

Comment: Is there a way you can check whether they are still running or not? @JamesWahlin

Comment: You can either run db.currentOp() (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) and look for the index build operation or tail the mongod log file.

Answer (score 1):

The mongo shell does not have to remain open once an index creation operation has been launched. The build will continue even if the shell is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Index creation on the DB is one time operation. You can confirm this by logging out off the shell and logging back in and query the indexes:
db.test.getIndexes()